# How to have a separated class loader for each test using Junit5

Tags: java, junit5

I have been trying to set up a Junit 5 extension to force every test to get a separate ClassLoader. I am able to do it quite easily in Junit4, creating my own BlockJUnit4ClassRunner. But, I fail to have it work now.

The purpose is to be able to test things such as static blocks or memorized fields in different states.

I have been trying to use the TestInstanceFactory without any success so far with something like that:

```java
public class SeparateClassLoaderExtension implements TestInstanceFactory {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object createTestInstance(TestInstanceFactoryContext factoryContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws TestInstantiationException {
        ClassLoader testClassLoader = new TestClassLoader();
        final Class<?> testClass = Class.forName(factoryContext.getTestClass().getName(), true, testClassLoader);

        Constructor<?> defaultConstructor = testClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        defaultConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        return defaultConstructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I get an exception from Junit saying that the class is not of the right type.

Someone any idea?

Answer (score 3):

JUnit Jupiter does **not** support this, yet. Here's the related issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/201

Comment: Yeah, I guess all we have to do is waiting. It is sad though... between that and PowerMock, switching 100% to Junit5 is difficult.

Comment: Don't just wait -- contribute! Discuss, create a proof-of-concept, ... a PR? ;-)